# How to filter empty value in a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to filter out empty value on email column.

So I tried this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__iexact='')
```

But, record has empty value would not be appeared.

Anyone know why is that?

Model is:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

Comment: What about this ? `user_queryset = User.objects.filter(email__isnull=True)`

Comment: I tried that, but only null value would be shown.
Thank you!

Comment: Your need to reword your question. What @JerinPeterGeorge wrote actually responds to your question. If you want to display all non-empty columns then take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Demetris correct me if i am wrong but null and empty are treated differently, aren't they? null=True would go along __isnull=True or i am missing somethin/

Comment: Thank you and my recognition is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to display all the emails that are not empty (filter-out empty) then you can exclude them using

```
users = User.objects.exclude(email__isnull=True)
```

If you want to get all the columns with empty email value then use

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
```

then:

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__isnull=True)
```

If you want to exclude empty value then:

```
users = User.objects.exclude(email__isnull=True)
```